# TSQL performance - JOIN on value BETWEEN min and max

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, performance, query-performance

I have two tables in which I store:

- an IP range - country lookup table
- a list of requests coming from different IPs

The IPs were stored as `bigint`s to improve lookup performance.

This is the table structure:

```
create table [dbo].[ip2country](
    [begin_ip] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [end_ip] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [begin_num] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [end_num] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IDCountry] [int] NULL,
    constraint [PK_ip2country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [begin_num] ASC,
        [end_num] ASC
    )
)

create table Request(
    Id int identity primary key, 
    [Date] datetime, 
    IP bigint, 
    CategoryId int
)
```

I want to get the request breakdown per country, so I perform the following query:

```
select 
    ic.IDCountry,
    count(r.Id) as CountryCount
from Request r
left join ip2country ic 
  on r.IP between ic.begin_num and ic.end_num
where r.CategoryId = 1
group by ic.IDCountry
```

I have a lot of records in the tables: about 200,000 in `IP2Country` and a few millions in `Request`, so the query takes a while.

Looking at the execution plan, the most expensive part is a Clustered Index Seek on index PK_IP2Country, which is executed many times (the number of rows in Request).

Also, something that I feel a little strange about is the `left join ip2country ic on r.IP between ic.begin_num and ic.end_num` part (don't know if there's a better way to perform the lookup).

The table structure, some sample data and query are available in SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a463e/3 (unfortunately I don't think I can insert many records to reproduce the problem, but this hopefully gives an idea).

I'm (obviously) not an expert in SQL performance/optimizations, so my question is: Are there any obvious ways in which this structure/query can be improved performance-wise that I am missing?

Comment: Can an IP address map to multiple countries?  If not, you can narrow your PK to just `begin_num`.  I also have to join on `A BETWEEN B AND C` fairly often, and I'm curious to know if there's a way to achieve this without tedious RBAR joins.

Comment: It's a little off-topic to your question, but I'd consider making `begin_ip` and `end_ip` persisted calculated columns, to prevent the possibility of the text and numbers getting out of synch somehow.

Comment: @w0lf: are there overlapping ranges in `ip2country (begin_num, end_num)` ?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades normally one IP should belong to a single country, so I think your idea of a query like `give me the first record that has a begin_num < ip in asc order of begin_num` (correct me if I'm wrong) could be be valid and improve performance.

Comment: @ypercube I just ran a query and noticed there are overlapping records. I think, however, that that's just an inconsistency and will try to get rid of those cases. Considering there's no overlap, do you see a way to make the query better?

Comment: @w0lf: My impressions is that that's basically what the server is doing in a case like this, because it first scans by `begin_num`, then scans by `end_num` within that set and only finds one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional index.  [In your Fiddle example I added:](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0433/1)

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_IP ON Request(CategoryID, IP)`

Which covers you for the request table and gets an index seek instead of a clustered index scan.

See how that improves it and let me know.  I'm guessing it'll help quite a bit since the scan on that index is I'm sure not cheap.

Comment: I don't know why, but the results seem to be different (in SQLFiddle)

Comment: @w0lf: they are different (probbaly) because you are both inserting random data into the tables.

Comment: @ypercube surely that's the cause. I've done so many things lately that I forgot that data was random. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the brute-force approach: you could explode your IP map.  Join a numbers table against your existing map to create one record per IP address.  That's only 267K records based on your Fiddle data, no problem at all.

```
CREATE TABLE IPLookup
  (
  IP  BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  CountryID  INT
  )
INSERT INTO IPLookup (IP, CountryID)
  SELECT
    N.Number, Existing.IDCountry
  FROM
    ip2country AS Existing
    INNER JOIN Numbers AS N ON N.Number BETWEEN Existing.begin_num AND Existing.end_num
```

This would make the seeks simpler, and hopefully faster.  This only makes sense if you make relatively few updates on `ip2country`, of course.

I hope someone else has a better a solution!

Comment: The whole data set would produce more than 5 billion records, so I don't think I'll do it. But this is a nice idea nevertheless; I'm sure it's feasible in many similar cases. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ic.IDCountry,
        COUNT(r.Id) AS CountryCount
FROM Request r
INNER JOIN (SELECT begin_num+NUMS.N [IP], IDCountry 
            FROM ip2country
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP(SELECT ABS(MAX(end_num-begin_num)) FROM ip2country) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sc.name)-1 [N]
                        FROM sys.columns sc) NUMS
            WHERE begin_num+NUMS.N <= end_num) ic
ON r.IP = ic.IP
WHERE r.CategoryId = 1
GROUP BY ic.IDCountry
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried your approach, but it seems to be more expensive than the initial query

Comment: How many rows do you have in each table? I would like to reproduce the scale of your problem on my DB and try to solve without adding an index :)

Comment: about 200,000 in IP2Country and a few millions (possibly tens of millions in the near future) in Request. I think if you solve it without indexes you deserve a "DBA of the year" title :)